# Toggle opacity change to checkbox images

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I want to change the opacity of the checkbox image to 1.0 (normal opacity) once the checkbox is checked and the default opacity set to 0.5 (half opacity). But I have no idea about the coding in JavaScript and CSS.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="n1" name="n1" style="display: none;" /><label for="n1"><img src="images/n1.png" width="20" height="20" /></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="n2" name="n2" style="display: none;" /><label for="n2"><img src="images/n2.png" width="20" height="20" /></label>

...

<input type="checkbox" id="n50" name="n50" style="display: none;" /><label for="n2"><img src="images/n50.png" width="20" height="20" /></label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with **no JS, just CSS:**

```
label img {
    opacity : 0.5;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label img {
    opacity : 1;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W2hHg/

Note that it uses the [adjacent sibling selector `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), so it relies on the label element immediately following the corresponding checkbox element.

But if you want to support IE<=8 which doesn't implement the [CSS `:checked` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3achecked) I would still suggest defining the `label img` class above to set the default opacity, then define the following class for when checked:

```
label.checked img {
    opacity : 1;
}
```

...and then add and remove that class using JS:

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    var el = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (el.type === "checkbox") {
        if (el.checked)
            el.nextSibling.className += " checked";
        else
            el.nextSibling.className = el.nextSibling.className.replace(/\bchecked\b/,"");
    }
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W2hHg/2/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('input:checkbox').click(function(){    

     var ImgId = 'img_'+$(this).attr('id');              
       if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
           $("#"+ImgId).css('opacity', '0.5');
         } else {
            $("#"+ImgId).css('opacity', '1');
          }             


        });//end click
 });//end ready
```

HTML:

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="n1" name="n1"  /><label for="n1"><img src="images/n1.png" width="20" height="20" id='img_n1' /></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="n2" name="n2" /><label for="n2"><img src="images/n2.png" width="20" height="20"  id='img_n2'/></label>
```

Comment: Why did you need to change the html? You can select the checkboxes with `$('input:checkbox')`, and then select the appropriate `img` with `$('label[for="' + this.id + '"]')`?

Comment: You are right, `$('label[for="' + this.id + '"]')` we can use that, but in his question,he is not give the importance for the `label` `for` attribute. thats why I wrapped this way.